# Complex index match 4 criteria partial text match wildcard

Tags: excel

[Main report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXvBL.png)

[Activity report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntfF4.png)

I am currently doing an internship and working on getting a set of reports done weekly. Before they had me doing this manually taking 3 or so hours to complete.

I wrote up a script to try to help me process this faster:

```
=INDEX('Activity Report Basic Test'!$E$3:$E$309,MATCH(1,INDEX((B4='Activity Report Basic Test'!$E$3:$E$309)*('exp Basic Test'!D4='Activity Report Basic Test'!$W$3:$W$309)*($K$1='Activity Report Basic Test'!$Z$3:$Z$309)*($H$1='Activity Report Basic Test'!$G$3:$G$309)*(MATCH("*"&C4&"*",'Activity Report Basic Test'!$H$3:$H$309&"",0)),0),0),0)
```

I wanted to try to automate as much as possible using the 5 criteria they wanted, using index match for Account Name, Expiration Date, Closed - S (closed successfully), Activity code, and the Line of Business Code(s).

For the LOB I have it set as a partial text match to cell range against wildcard.

For some reason it is only working with a few (very miniscule results). I do not know where to move forward with this. Any help would be great.

Comment: You can't message anyone on SO. Please turn your input in a format that you can publish here.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I appreciate it! Let me do a quick screen grab and post of the reports and where the issue is then.

Comment: Added two images that show the report script and data - Thank you fodma1 for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few days ago, with only 3 criteria for INDEX/MATCH. I eventually solved the problem by using =Countifs with the criteria. I found this way to be significantly easier than MATCH/INDEX (although some might disagree), in that you can quickly scan the numbers, and figure out if something is missing or too many are included.

Comment: Thank you for that, let me try it out and send everyone a snapshot of what I have afterwards and see if all the compliances are met - again thank you guys - my first time posting on SO after being an onlooker since highschool, and I am really impressed by the speed and help fot he community.

Comment: Hi so I changed this to a countif multiple criteria with partial cell match - the countif for 4 of the five criteria works no problem - getting the martial match though is proving difficult as it is returning a #value error.

Comment: Using the script: =IF((COUNTIFS('Activity Report Basic Test'!$E$5:$E$309,'exp Basic Test'!B4,'Activity Report Basic Test'!$AV$5:$AV$309,'exp Basic Test'!D4,'Activity Report Basic Test'!$Z$5:$Z$309,'exp Basic Test'!$K$1,'Activity Report Basic Test'!$G$5:$G$309,'exp Basic Test'!$H$1)*(MATCH("*"&C4&"*",'Activity Report Basic Test'!$H$3:$H$309&"",0))),"Yes","No")

Comment: Looking through your formula, it may not be a case of using MATCH. I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve with the MATCH. I suggest that instead, you put the final value as part of the countifs, using "Yes" or "No" as the final parameter